# How to read/translate macOS 12 (Monterey) .ips crash files?

Tags: json, macos, crash-reports

Starting in macOS 12 (Monterey), the system apparently writes crash file as `.ips` files, instead of the traditional `.crash` file format.

The file appears to contain JSON data:

```json
{"app_name":"Helper","timestamp":"2021-10-30 18:49:32.00 +0100","app_version":"3.0.0(66) beta","slice_uuid":"673198dd-94ac-31a7-9e81-09fe6c781255","build_version":"3.0.0.66","platform":1,"bundleID":"com.dislt.helper","share_with_app_devs":0,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"macOS 12.0.1 (21A559)","incident_id":"CC03C2EC-C1D4-4F6E-AA1F-6C4EC555D6B8","name":"Helper"}
{
  "uptime" : 91000,
  "procLaunch" : "2021-10-30 18:49:29.7791 +0100",
  "procRole" : "Unspecified",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "MacBookPro14,3",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 91844701503187,
  "coalitionID" : 1244,
  "osVersion" : {
    "train" : "macOS 12.0.1",
    "build" : "21A559",
    "releaseType" : "User"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2021-10-30 18:49:32.4572 +0100",
  "incident" : "92A89610-D70A-4D93-A974-A9018BB5C72A",
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "pid" : 77765,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 91847378271126,
  "cpuType" : "X86-64",
  "procName" : "Helper",
  ...
```

When I preview the file or open it in the Console app, a traditional crash report is automatically generated:

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               Helper [77765]
Path:                  /Users/USER/Library/Application Support/Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Helper
Identifier:            com.distl.helper
Version:               3.0.0(66) beta (3.0.0.66)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        TestBead [77726]
Responsible:           TestBead [77726]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-10-30 18:49:32.4572 +0100
OS Version:            macOS 12.0.1 (21A559)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     3.0 (14Y908)
Anonymous UUID:        CC03C2EC-C1D4-4F6E-AA1F-6C4EC555D6B8


Time Awake Since Boot: 91000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        1  Dispatch queue: com.apple.NSXPCConnection.user.anonymous.77726

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00007f780071a000
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x00007f780071a000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process:   exc handler [77765]
...
```

I have customer support and development tools that scan these crash report files automatically, and I'd like to find out if there's a way to automate the translation of the JSON data back into the traditional crash report format?

I'd like to do this to (a) avoid rewriting my crash report scanning tools (although that wouldn't be impossible), and (b) automatically translate these files into a human readable format, without resorting to opening the file in the Console app.

Comment: Have you run into reports with empty version numbers? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/70584180/43615

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've run into the same problem. I haven't tried it myself yet, but someone has already created an `ips2crash` command available at [GitHub](https://github.com/packagesdev/ips2crash). As the name implies, it should convert an `.ips` file to the (now) legacy crash report format.

Comment: Thanks for that! I did not find this in my original search. I downloaded the project and found it wouldn't initially parse my crash reports. But I found the problem, fixed it, and sent a pull request to the original author.

Comment: Have you run into reports with empty version numbers? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/70584180/43615

Comment: I haven't. Although I will note that the app version is obtained from the app bundle info, so naked executables won't get one. Also for any situation where the bundle can't be identified, located, read, parsed, .... I do have a problem that the current version of ips2crash in that it doesn't parse the Application Specific Backtrace, which if you use a lot of deferred blocks (as my app does) is just about the only place to find the code that crashed. I need to take some time this weekend to look into that.

Comment: I'm finding myself needing this tool, but there are no Makefiles or docs on how to compile it. Very unfortunate.

Comment: @Jim there is an Xcode project in the tool_ips2crash folder you can build via Xcode. Unfortunately the tool is not working for me -- I'm getting "An error occurred when reading the file" when passing it an ips file

Comment: That is unfortunate. I don't ever use xcode, so I'm not familiar with how to use. I'll google that.